# How to add a certain number of days based on field value

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm working on creating a view to convert some values that we get coming in for dates/times. (I've figured out the times already.) In this table, dates come in the format of "Days after 12-31-1840." I'm trying to create a view that shows the actual dates/times rather than in this format. This is what I have so far:

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(FLWSHT_MEAS_NM) LIKE '%DATE' THEN TO_CHAR(DATE '1840-12-31' + INTERVAL ACUTE_MEASURE_VALUE DAY)
```

I know that this is the correct syntax for adding dates, because I'm able to get the view working with this instead:

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(FLWSHT_MEAS_NM) LIKE '%DATE' THEN TO_CHAR(DATE '1840-12-31' + INTERVAL '30' DAY)
```

My question is, how do I add a specific number of days based on the ACUTE_MEASURE_VALUE field? I'm not able to run the code to get a runtime error as it's coming up as a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Teradata documentation:

> Teradata SQL extends the ANSI SQL:2011 standard to allow the operations of adding or subtracting a number of days from an ANSI DATE value.  Teradata SQL treats the number as an INTERVAL DAY value.

I'm assuming your field ACUTE_MEASURE_VALUE is already in your table and is an integer.  The words INTERVAL and DAY are part of the specification of interval **constants** - this is a variable and syntactically you don't use those keywords.

`...TO_CHAR(DATE '1840-12-31' + ACUTE_MEASURE_VALUE)...`

Just drop the INTERVAL keyword and the DAY keyword and it should work.

By the way, why are you using To_Char() in this?  By transforming it into a character string it preempts anyone using this view from performing calculations on this date.  If you leave the view in DATE format then any subsequent Select from this view has a lot more flexibility in manipulating this data field.

Comment: PERFECT! I just had to cast ACUTE_MEASURE_VALUE to integer as well but that worked. As for the TO_CHAR, I work for a medical center and all of our patient's flowsheet values are stored in this table. There's thousands of different types of measures, told apart by the FLWSHT_MEAS_NM or FLWSHT_ID fields. I need to keep all the values as VARCHARs because there aren't just dates or integers stored in that field, there could be airway types, Y/N questions, etc. If we ever need to do calculations, we'll usually just select those specific FLWSHT_IDs and cast them to dates/integers. Thanks again!